# Compare range of time in two worksheets and fill the cells between ranges with a color

Tags: vba, excel, time, conditional-formatting

There are two sheets. The first is dynamically updating and obtaining time of starting databases updating and ending time of that. The second one contains the time what's borrowed from the first one and names of each DB what was updated for each day of weeks. The question is that how to fill cells with a color between the range of time for each updated DB?

There's an example of the first sheet:

```
  1        2         3 
DB_NAME  start     end
  DB1    20:30    21:02
  DB2    22:04    22:26
  DB3    19:05    22:10
```

There's an example of the second sheet:

```
 1        2         3       4      5
DAY      TIME      DB1      DB2    DB3
MON     19:05       '        '      '
        20:30       '        '      '
        21:02       '        '      '
        22:04       '        '      '
        22:10       '        '      '
        22:26       '        '      '
TUE     00:25       -        -      -
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a conditional formatting rule based on the following formula,

```
=AND(INDEX(Sheet4!$B:$B, MATCH(C$1, Sheet4!$A:$A, 0))<=$B2, INDEX(Sheet4!$C:$C, MATCH(C$1, Sheet4!$A:$A, 0))>=$B2)
```

VBA,

```
Option Explicit

Sub timeCFR()
    With Worksheets("sheet5")
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "C"), .Cells(8, "E"))
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
              Formula1:="=AND(INDEX(Sheet4!$B:$B, MATCH(C$1, Sheet4!$A:$A, 0))<=$B2, INDEX(Sheet4!$C:$C, MATCH(C$1, Sheet4!$A:$A, 0))>=$B2)"
            .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: apparently I am doing something wrong. That's same table but my example can't be executed. There's run-time error 5 and it doesn't move in spite of correct data. Also I figured out that while extending of number of servers I can just add `INDEX(Sheet1!$D:$D, MATCH(C$1, Sheet1!$A:$A, 0))<=$B2` into the formula.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you could accomplish this. (Six ways, off the top of my head!)

Here's one that **doesn't require VBA**...

If the end-goal is to provide a "graphic indication of completion", I think the simplest method (and therefore most easily adaptable to future changes) and also "most aesthetic for the least work," would be to display [Unicode block characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements) (ie., `█`), rather than trying to fill the cells dynamically.

---

[image: img]

- Enter this formula in `C7` (and then copy/paste to the rest of your range):

  ```
  =IF(AND($B8>VLOOKUP(C$6,ssTimes,2,FALSE),$B7<=VLOOKUP(C$6,ssTimes,3,FALSE)),"█████","")
  ```
- **`ssTimes`** is a named range for Start/Stop times lookup in **`A2:C4`**.
- Other symbols (ie., `░▒▓ ▌▌▌● ☺`) can also be substituted to different data or conditions, or just <del>for aesthetic purposes</del> to be .